# Calculated column to Split text

Tags: calculated-column

I need to split column into two columns

```
Column1: SHPS011SSAD 
Column2: SH
Column3: PS
```

What would be the calculated formula for this?

Comment: Does it always be fixed length for Column2 to be initial two characters and Column3 to be two characters after two characters ?

Answer (score 2):

Column2:

```
=LEFT(Column1, 2)
```

Column3:

```
=RIGHT(LEFT(Column1, 4), 2)
```

**FYI**
Calculated columns use formula from Microsoft Excel... So if you want to generate formula for Calculated Columns easy way is to generate formula in Microsoft Excel first!

I hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

=Column1&Column2&Column3

Comment: Sorry for that - I miss that you split into two columns.